# Lua string.gsub replace pattern

Tags: string, lua, reverse, gsub

I'm working on a graphing calculator program.  I have a graph that displays the 'y=' functions.

If a pattern such as 'x * 5' is found (where x is multiplied by something, but x is given first) I want to replace it with 5x.  This is what I currently have.

```
local func = "x * 5"
print(func:gsub("%*", ""):gsub(" ", ""):gsub("x%d+", "%d+x"))

--[[
    get rid of the '*' symbol, get rid of spaces, then 
    replace x(digit) with (digit)x

    EXPECTED OUTPUT: 5x, OUTPUT: d+x
]]
```

I was thinking I could probably use the string.reverse function, but I don't know how to approach this.  Can anyone help?

UPDATE:  This is what I have now.  It's outputting '2x.5'

```
local func = "x * 5"
print(func:gsub("%*", ""):gsub(" ", ""):gsub("x%d+", function(match) return match:sub(2) .. match:sub(1, 1))
```

Comment: `string.reverse` will work for that simple case. It will not for `x * 2.5`. The `gsub` call there needs to capture the digits in the pattern and use a pattern reference in the replacement.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.  How could I go about doing that?

Comment: `:gsub("x([%d.]+)", "%1x")` But you also aren't, in that snippet at least, ensuring that your input is in the format you expect. That `gsub` chain isn't going to do much of use for `2x + 5` or `x * y`.

Comment: I'm sorry to say (because it's not as simple as what you are hoping to do) but you really need to write up a parser grammar, perhaps using LPeg.

Comment: I actually figured out a simple way to do it.  Instead of parsing the function to display it (basically from 5 * x to 5x), I decided to do the exact opposite.  I made it so you can enter 3x into the function, and the script will turn it into 3 * x then execute it using loadstring.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @david I think you should make your comment into an answer and accept it so the answer can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured out a simple way to do it. Instead of parsing the function to display it (basically from 5 * x to 5x), I decided to do the exact opposite. I made it so you can enter 3x into the function, and the script will turn it into 3 * x then execute it using loadstring. Thanks for the help.